# How does > /dev/null eat up output streams?

Tags: bash, unix, dev-null

I've used `/dev/null` a lot in bash programming to send unnecessary output into a black hole.

For example, this command:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' > /dev/null
$
```

Will not `echo` anything. I've read that `/dev/null` is an empty file used to dispose of unwanted output through redirection. But how exactly does this disposal take place? I can't imagine `/dev/null` writing the content to a file and then immediately deleting that file. So what actually happens when you redirect to this file?

Comment: The computer black hole eat it. That's what my colleague told me ;-)

Comment: `/dev/null` is not a real file. It is a pseudofile device that simply discards any data written to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>/dev/null` redirects the command standard output to the null device, which is a special device which discards the information written to it.
It's all implemented via file_operations (`drivers/char/mem.c` if you're curious to look yourself):

```
static const struct file_operations null_fops = {
    .llseek     = null_lseek,
    .read       = read_null,
    .write      = write_null,
    .splice_write   = splice_write_null,
};
```

write_null is what's called when you write to /dev/null. It always returns the same number of bytes that you write to it:

```
static ssize_t write_null(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
              size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    return count;
}
```

That's it. The buffer is just ignored.

Comment: So in effect `/dev/null` is a symlink to some device whose involvement in any operation triggers this function?

Comment: @cs95 Symbolic links and device nodes are different concepts. Symlinks point to other files while device passes operations to *drivers*, which contains device-specific code to handle all kinds of operations (e.g. `/dev/full` will reject any non-zero writes).